# Django formsets required

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

How to make all forms in django formset required? I tried to validate presence of all fields in `cleaned_data` overriding formset's clean() method but it just fails silently without any error displayed.

Thanks!

Source code:

```
class BaseScheduleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseScheduleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['day'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        self.fields['user'].widget = forms.HiddenInput()

    class Meta:
        model = Schedule

    def clean_end_time(self):
        start_time = self.cleaned_data.get('start_time')
        end_time = self.cleaned_data['end_time']

        if start_time and end_time:
            if end_time <= start_time:
                raise forms.ValidationError("End time must be later that start time.")
        return end_time

class BaseScheduleFormset(forms.models.BaseModelFormSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseScheduleFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for number, weekday in enumerate(WEEKDAYS):
            self.forms[number].day_name = weekday[1]

    def clean(self):
        raise forms.ValidationError('You must specify schedule for the whole week')

ScheduleFormset = forms.models.modelformset_factory(Schedule, extra=7, max_num=7,
    form=BaseScheduleForm, formset=BaseScheduleFormset)
```

There are 7 forms each for one day and all of them must be filled to be valid. In example above I just tried to raise error in clean. `is_valid()` became False, but no errors were displayed.

Comment: Can you please give more details and source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand **where** the errors are not being displayed.

If is_valid is False, then good, the validation it self is working. Then the next place to look is for the templating layer. How are you checking for errors? {{form.errors}} or {{somefield.errors}}.

The way the clean methods are setup here, their errors will not be associated with any fields, but should go in the **all** erros slot.

Cheers

Comment: formset.errors is empty though formset.is_valid() is false. Looks like a bug for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and figured out where these errors were stored by checking the source.  When you override the clean method of a formset and raise a validation error the errors are stored in the non_form_errors property.

So in your template you would need to add the following assuming the template variable for formset is named 'formset':

```
{{ formset.non_form_errors }}
```