# Django: Make all formset forms required?

Tags: django, django-forms

Exactly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636923/django-formsets-required), except that one got closed and accepted without a real answer. It looks like I can use a custom formset and override the clean method, but that still doesn't answer how I check that they're all filled in. What properties am I supposed to be looking at?

> The formset is *smart* enough to ignore extra forms that were not changed.

*Screams* This has caused me nothing but agony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I found the solution by digging through the source...

```
class BaseVehicleFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        for i in range(self.total_form_count()):
            if not self.forms[i].has_changed():
                raise ValidationError("All vehicle forms must be filled in. Press \"remove\" if you've added too many.")
```

Comment: hi! I trying to do something similar with your question. I have a formset with two forms. I would like the user to select an option for each form. In your answer you're saying the user to select everything? that's what i understood.. or i can use the same approach in my problem? Thanks!

Comment: yes...this should require them fill out *all* the forms. it checks each form to ensure that its been changed (from its default/blank state) and throws an error if not.

Comment: thank you! I had a question for that subject, if you want to close it or answer it with this code, I will accept it. Or I can also answer and redirect to your question!

Comment: @pavid: if you link to it i can.

Comment: well actually, this isn't working.. I have some errors for sure, because my form is always valid, even if I only select one option..

Comment: but if you want to check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966993/both-forms-in-formset-need-to-be-selected

Comment: Thank you Mark! It worked, I was just using the wrong error on template