# both forms in formset need to be selected

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a formset that have two forms.

forms:

```
class PresClinicForm(forms.Form):
    _names = list(PresClinic.objects.values_list('pres_clinic_id', 'pres_clinic_name'))
    _names.append(["New", u'Nova entrada'])

    pres_name = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(), choices=_names, label=
        "", required=True)

PresClinicFormSet = formset_factory(PresClinicForm, extra=2)
```

views:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset1 = PresClinicFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='pres_clinic')
    if formset1.is_valid():
        choice = formset1.cleaned_data
    return render_to_response('template.html', {'options': options})
```

template:

```
    <form method="post" action="">
    <div>
    {{ formset1.management_form}}
        {% for form in formset1.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
    </div>    
</form>
```

The user has to select one option in each form.
I tried required=True into forms.py but if I select only one option, it works anyway..

It shouldn't work if the user only select an option. That's what I trying to implement..

Does someone knows how to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check Mark's question for this answer:
[Django: Make all formset forms required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783519/django-make-all-formset-forms-required)

Be careful, you can only use formset with django 1.3, with django 1.1 cleaned_data gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Matthew Flanagan's code for requiring at least one form in a formset to be valid as a starting point and integrate that into your workflow: http://wadofstuff.blogspot.com/2009/08/requiring-at-least-one-inline-formset.html

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I end up using Mark's code. I f you see on the right the linked questions he has a answer for this situation :)