# formset is valid but form has no attribute cleaned_data!

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

Ok, so I have a formset that is valid. But gives me a error that that form has no attribute cleaned_data..

Honestly I have absolutely no clue what's happening..
I tried my code on terminal and it returned a empty dictionary.. without errors..

forms:

```
class Clinical(forms.Form):
    _names = list(ClinicalForm.objects.values_list('form_id', 'form_name'))
    _names.append(("New", u'Nova entrada'))

    cliform_name = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect(), choices=_names, label
         ="", required=True)
```

views:

```
ClinicalSet = formset_factory(Clinical, extra=2)

formset2 = ClinicalSet(request.POST)
if formset2.is_valid():
    choice1 = formset2.cleaned_data
    return render_to_response('valid_test.html', 
                                {
                                    'formset2': formset2,
                                    'wrongs1': wrongs1,
                                    'choice1': choice1 
                                    })
else:
    formset2 = ClinicalSet()
return render_to_response('valid_test.html', 
                            {
                                'formset2': formset2,
                                'wrongs1': wrongs1,
                                })
```

template:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
{{ formset2.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset2.forms %}
        {{ form }}
    {% endfor %} 
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</div>
```

If I comment the line where the cleaned_data is called (choice1), I don't receive any error and I'm able to see the forms..
If I select some options and uncomment this line, it works..

I have a similar formset : [both forms in formset need to be selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966993/both-forms-in-formset-need-to-be-selected) and this one works..

the form that works is the first formset (linked above). The post parameters:

```
form-0-pres_name    1
form-1-pres_name    2
form-INITIAL_FORMS  0
form-TOTAL_FORMS    2
```

the user select one option in each form and he's redirect to another view (this one - formset2).

Any help is more than welcome..

Comment: What Django version are you using? This should be fixed in 1.3: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11418

Comment: humm I'm using 1.1. BUt I already have a formset working. pretty much like this one but the data inside is different

Comment: After looking at the ticket @Mark Lavin mentioned, I'd say it's a pretty safe bet that's your issue. I can't say why or how your other formset works, but you should probably just modify your code to check for the presence of `cleaned_data` via `hasattr` and respond accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`formset_factory` returns a form iterator, i.e. essentially a list of forms, it is not a form itself. `cleaned_data` is only available on the form, so you have to iterate over `formset2`:

```
for form in formset2:
    form.cleaned_data # Here I am!
```

Comment: this gives me the same error. actually I had already tried this before. Why I don't understand this error is because I have a similar formset and that formset works. I gone edit my question to let this clear

Comment: So are you saying it's only the initial view that generates the error? When you say "If I select some options and uncomment this line, it works.." do you mean uncommenting the line before you submit the form?

Comment: this error appears before I'm able to see the forms. If I comment the line choice1 = formset2.cleaned_data, I see the forms and I'm able to select, and the post return the values I've selected. But if I uncomment the line (to be able to access these values and work with them) and restart the process the error continues

Comment: Yep, then I'd definitely say the ticket above is in play. Just check if the formset has cleaned_data before trying to use it. When it doesn't that means there's nothing in it anyways, so you can just pass an empty list to the template instead.

Comment: but why does the previous one works then? Because it's the same thing.. I've update my question with the post parameters from the previous formset.. perhaps it could help

Comment: ok, so I've done something similar whit your suggestion. I don't have anymore the line cleaned_data. I've inserted an if saying if request.POST.keys() is empty then return only the forms, else return the selected values. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If someone need, here are the modifications I've done in the view:

```
 ClinicalSet = formset_factory(Clinical, extra=tamanh)

 #size of this list will determine number of forms
 wrongs = iter(wrong)
 formset = ClinicalSet(request.POST)
 dic = {}
 if formset.is_valid():
     if len(request.POST.keys()) == 0:
         return render_to_response('valid.html',  
                                        {
                                            'formset': formset,
                                            'wrongs': wrongs })
     else:
         #+ 2 because of TOTAL_FORMS and MAX_NUM_FORMS
         if len(request.POST.keys()) != len(wrongs) + 2:
             msg = "You have to select something in all forms!!"
             return render_to_response('valid.html', 
                                            {
                                                'formset': formset,
                                                'wrongs': wrongs,
                                                'msg': msg })
         else:
             for n in range(tamanh):
                 #result post into a dictionary, since cleaned_data doesn't work
                 dic[wrongs.next()] = request.POST['form-' + str(n) + '-cliform_name']
                 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('valid2', args=[word]))
    else:
        formset = ClinicalSet()
    return render_to_response('valid.html', 
                                {
                                    'formset': formset,
                                    'wrongs': wrongs,
                                    'msg': msg
                                    })
```

Comment: What do you do if your form within a formset contains a FileField? You cannot use `request.POST` in this case. I tried `request.FILES`, but without luck.