# Getting my formset to validate on the number of valid filled in forms

Tags: django

I want the user to fill in exactly 3 forms in my formset, there are of course only 3 forms in my formset on the frontend but I want to make sure a user doesn't craft it's own POST. I've come up with this:

```
class ThisFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        results = super(ThisFormset, self).clean()
        count = len(filter(lambda f: f.is_valid() and f.clean(), self.forms))

        if count != 3:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Must fill in 3")

        return results
```

Is there a better way of doing the `len(filter(lambda f: f.is_valid() and f.clean(), self.forms))` portion to get the count?

Answer (score 0):

See: [Django: Make all formset forms required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783519/django-make-all-formset-forms-required) for an example of requiring all forms in a formset to be valid.